# When space bends, what are the lines that are being bent?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

In an electric field diagram, the lines represent the electrostatic force vector at the position.    These lines are bent when you place a charge into the system.

What is the equivalent description of the "lines" that are being bent when a mass is placed into an area of space?

Comment: Here is a favorite link: [Foundations by Greg Egan](http://gregegan.customer.netspace.net.au/FOUNDATIONS/). Read through that for an understanding of what is meant by *curvature* in this sense.

Answer (score 5):

> When space bends, what are the lines that are being bent?

The straight ones.

For example: say you have two parallel laser beams traveling through space. Photons travel in a "straight line" more or less by definition, i.e. the path of a laser beam is the straightest line humans can produce, so it is a benchmark of sorts. Mathematically two parallel beams should never cross. Now we introduce into the scenario a massive object such as a star, past which the two beams pass on either side. The two beams are traveling in a straight line each before they pass the star; they travel in a straight line each after passing the star; and as far as we can tell, they travel in a straight line each as they are passing the star. So in theory, if they each travel in a straight line through their entire path, they should remain parallel after passing the star. However, because space is curved near the star, the straight lines that the lasers are traveling become unparallel, and somewhere on the far side of the star they cross paths.

Another example: if a planet is flying through space it should travel in a straight line if there's nothing pushing it some other direction (like a rocket engine or some such). Just for kicks we'll say it's traveling directly toward the nose of Ursa Major. Now let's say a star comes ambling along near the planet; due to the curvature of space around the massive star, the path of the planet deflects away from its straight Ursa-bound course, possibly even being captured in orbit around the star. There still isn't anything pushing the planet off course, but its "straight line" is changing due to the curvature of space.

Note that in this second case, the star will also deflect past (or orbit around) the planet by a small amount, the exact amount being proportional to the ratio of masses between the planet and the star. This is because the planet curves space a little bit, just as the star curves it by a lot.

Comment: You are giving the OP an infinity of definitions of "straight". Which trajectory an object takes in curved spacetime depends on the velocity of that object. This is already true in Newtonian mechanics and it gets even more complicated in general relativity.

Comment: @CuriousOne Oooer.   Interesting, because the answer sounds compelling!    So ... can I check this: the definition of 'straight' is not the trajectory of any arbitrary object at arbitrary speed.  Rather, it is the trajectory of light at light speed.   I think the answer says that it is this trajectory that is getting bent (bent relative to what is another question!)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: It starts out quite OK, if one sticks to light beams, but in the second part where the explanation moves on to massive objects it just falls apart. There is, of course, a real problem with all of this: an accelerated observer sees everything distorted, which includes every observer who is not at infinity in "flat" space, so the definition of curved vs. straight is not as simple as in Newtonian mechanics where observations to not depend on the state of motion of the observer. dmeckee has a better definition IMHO.

Comment: One shortcoming is that you talk about lines and curvature of space, while you should be talking about world-lines and curvature of space-time.

Comment: I think a vital word needs mentioning to make this an ideal answer: topology. Ultimately space-time is a surface and the lines illustrate the topology of that surface. It's also worth noting that the lines are only representative of the spatial topology, naturally bodies moving at different velocities are going to have different curvatures and a different idea of what 'straight' is.

Comment: I think that the long paragraph is using "mathematically" and "in theory" in a very vague sense: I thought general relativity is described by mathematics but this answer implies it's unmathematical? In which theory?

Comment: In the second example, the star will alter the course of the planet for two reasons. One is that its mass creates a curvature in space (or space-time), as the answer says. The other (and much larger) effect is that the start acts on the planet by gravitational attraction $m_0m_1G/r^2$. The first example is fine because photons have no mass and so are not affected by gravitational attraction.

Answer (score 3):

The field line mind picture in General Relativity is probably not useful, at least not for me, aside from in very special cases, because

1. The dimension of the pictures you're trying to see at is too high for our everyday spatial intuition to help us much - you're trying to visualize a rank 2, $4\times 4$ tensor with 10 independent components (the metric), not a force vector as in electrostatics or Newtonian Gravity. In Newtonian or weak field Einstein equation gravity, the $g_{0\,0}$ component becomes the analogue of the gravitational potential $\phi$, so the mind picture you seek becomes that of Newtonian gravity with force lines along $\nabla\,\phi$. But these are not the lines of "bent space";
2. Gravity is not a force in GTR. Nor can you define a global system of co-ordinates that allows you to define an "acceleration field" that would stand in for it. You can only define acceleration relative to locally comoving inertial frames, which is what an accelerometer measures. So, around a planet, for example, you could plot an acceleration field *relative to the planet's surface*. So you're really back to the Newtonian picture.

Don't get too hung up about the words "bent spacetime, warped spacetime", because you *can't* visualize them: our evolution in Neogene East Africa on Planet Earth did not kit us out for kenning such patterns - their recognition wasn't useful for finding food and water or keeping clear of Neogene Lions. They cause a great deal of needless feelings that "I'm never going to be able to understand this stuff". I really do think abstraction is your friend here: "bent spacetime" simply means that if you take a vector and parallel transport it around a loop in that spacetime, it will have changed to a different vector when you come back to your beginning point. Or, alternatively, bent spacetime means that geometry done there will not fulfil all of Euclid's axioms. Angles inside triangles don't add up to $180^\circ$. That's all there is to it. This variation around a path is called [holonomy  - look this up here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy). The object used to measure this is a rank four object: it must take as inputs two vectors (which define the edges infinitessimal parallelogram that you imagine a vector being transported around) and spits out a *matrix* which defines the transformation any vector undergoes in being transported around a loop. Thankfully, we can pare this down to a rank two object which has simpler geometrical meanings, and one of the best elementary accounts of the meanings of all of this is to be found in [Chapter 42 of Volume 2 of the Feynman Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_42.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you plot grid-lines on a graph what are the grid-lines?

Well, on a typical 2D plot with x increasing to the right and y increasing upward, the horizontal grid-lines are the loci of constant y and the vertical grid-lines are the loci of constant x.

In 3D the grid lines are the loci of constant x and y for the ones that run parallel to the z-axis and of constant y and z for grid-lines running parallel to the x-axis and so on.

That is what is shown in those visualizations of bent space: loci of constant values for some set of time and space coordinates.

Comment: I find this answer hard to relate to because if it truly were the case that lines of constant X,Y (for example) were being bent, then we couldn't tell.    What would we be referring/comparing to.   I think that the grid system stays fixed in space, and lines of (as the other answer says) "straightness" bend.   Therefore in the presence of mass, a given straight line is a different set of X,Y,Z than in empty space.  It's not the grid that bends, it's the definition (behaviour, I guess actually) of straightness against the fixed grid.

Comment: The visualization you are using when you say *" I think that the grid system stays fixed in space, and lines of (as the other answer says) "straightness" bend"* is what mathematicians refer to as embedding a geometry in a higher dimensional space. You can do differential geometry that way, but it is not necessary. Your notion of "straight" is conditioned by living is a realm well approximated by Cartesian space. Light goes straight by definition so when the Asher talks of initially parallel beams converging he means that the grid-lines no longer act the way you expect them to.

Comment: That sounds right.   For me, I think the reason why I am compelled to do that (embed...) is that my own "referential system" (and everyone's I assert) is like that.  So for example when I shine a laser along a line of constant X,Y and then put a big mass next to the beam, I _experience_ that the X,Y of the line changes.  So it appears to be self evident that it is not the grid that we all use to measure space that is bending.

Answer (score 1):

When people talk about curvature of space, they are usually talking about two related ideas: 1) the curvature of world-lines in 3+1-space-time or 2) the curvature of light paths in 3-space. These ideas are related as light behaves as the high-speed, low-mass limit.

1) Consider a 2D surface embedded in a 3D flat space. At any point on the surface, there is a tangent plane. If the surface is curved, then as we slide the tangent plane from one point to another, the angles it makes with respect to the fixed 3-dimensional axes changes.

Now, consider a particle moving at a constant unit speed along this surface. We can project its velocity vector onto the fixed 3-dimensional axes. At each point along the curve, the components of the velocity change, but the total magnitude of the velocity remains the same.

To make the connection with spacetime, we let the one dimension be time, the other two are space, and our constant unit speed is the rate of proper time of the particle. The curve traced out by the particle is its worldline, and the ratio of its spatial components to its time component is the observed velocity of the particle. If we consider a particle moving in a straight line in flat space, then a force causing it to speed up causes its world line to curve toward the spatial plane, and a force causing it to slow down causes the world line to curve toward the time axis.

2) To describe a 3D space which is not flat, I like to think about sponges. A flat space is represented by a homogeneous sponge. If we place a mass in a homogeneous sponge, then it pulls the sponge toward it with a distance-dependent force. The effect is that the sponge gets more and more dense as you approach the mass.

A beam of light seeks out the straightest, maximum spatial component, constant speed path it can find. While particles could slow-down/speed up when the density of the space-sponge changes, the beam of light does not have this option, so it deflects to optimize its path.

Comment: I plan on adding some more using pictures like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Introduction_to_general_relativity#/media/File:Spacetime_curvature.png) when I get the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Pictures like the one you linked to are the very thing I find worst about trying to understand this.   In those pictures, it looks like gravity pulled the earth down into the grid ... which raises the question what pulls masses "into" the space-time grid.   Using gravity to explain gravity is bad, IMHO.   A picture like that, but _flat_ would be helpful.  [This picture](https://lifeandphysics.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/curvature.jpg) is also good.